# Forcing SSL & www subdomain for any URI entered with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, subdomain

I have an SSL certificate for the 'www' subdomain of a web site we'll call example.com.

Therefore I can force SSL, but if the user doesn't enter 'www.example.com' into their browser, the SSL certificate appears invalid.

I wish to accomplish this with mod_rewrite rules in an .htaccess file at the root of the web site.

No matter what URI the user enters, (e.g. example.com, www.example.com, https://example.com, example.com/folder/file.html, etc.), I want to force the HTTPS *and* the www subdomain, keeping whatever URI they provided, of course.

I was playing around with the .htaccess file and some rules, as I've already done some research, but I don't have much experience with mod_rewrite or .htaccess.  I think I found the SVN revision that *almost* worked for me, but not quite.  Here it is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Try not to laugh too hard at my file; it is mostly derived from examples I found online.

Any pointers are appreciated! =)

Comment: Also: use example.com for example domains (fixed it for you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Comment: Modified from your original (which had %{HTTP_HOST} in the RewriteRule line, which I see you've already fixed) it works great: RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]